# Get array value with unknown key name

Tags: php

If I have an associate array with only one key and one element `myArray =array("myKey"=>123)`, but I don't know the name of the key, how do I get the value?  For instance, if I don't know my key is called myKey, how do I return 123? I know I can use `foreach($myArray as $key=>$value)` but I feel there should be a better way.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use [`current()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php):

```
$value = current($array);
```

or, if you want the key as well, [`each()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php):

```
list($key, $value) = each($array);
```

Comment: Never heard of current().  Let me test it.  Thanks

Comment: Love it. Thank you!

Comment: [each function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 8.0.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively in my case, I also needed the keyname.

```
$key = key($array);

$value = $array[$key];
```

Get the key name from array then use the key to get the value from array.

Answer (score 0):

Since **php7.3** you can use [`array_key_first`](https://www.php.net/array_key_first):

```
$myArray = array("myKey"=>123);
$key = array_key_first($myArray);
echo $myArray[$key];    // outputs 123
```